# Unable to remote to VM instance with Oracle Linux 8.6 and XRDP using Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, graphical-user-interface, oracle-linux, xrdp

I created a VM instance on Oracle Cloud, using Oracle Linux 8.6. I added TCP 3389 port in VCN on OCI before installing GUI.

I want to install GUI and allow RDP connection to VM instance, so I installed GNome GUI and XRDP with the following commands (`#` is I use root user):

```
# dnf groupinstall "Server with GUI" -y
# systemctl set-default graphical
# reboot
```

Then uncomment the following line in the `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` file to ensure that VNC uses X.org instead of Wayland:

```
WaylandEnable=False
```

After that, I installed TigerVNC Server and XRDP:

```
# yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm -y
# yum install tigervnc-server xrdp -y
# systemctl start xrdp
# systemctl enable xrdp
# firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=3389/tcp
# firewall-cmd --reload
```

Then, I proceeded to [set the VNC password, configure VNC service and set up the VNC service](https://docs.oracle.com/en/learn/install-vnc-oracle-linux/#set-the-vnc-password) as instructed on Oracle's document page.

Finally, I proceeded to connect to VM Instance via Remote Desktop Connection, but I received `An authentication error has occurred. The function requested is not supportted`:

[image: An authentication error has occurred. The function requested is not supportted]

After that, I revised the `port` field in the `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini` file into `port=tcp://:3389` and then restarted the XRDP service via `service xrdp restart` command, then check the status of XRDP service through `systemctl status xrdp` command:

[image: systemctl status xrdp]

But when I tried to reconnect, the above error still happened. I conducted a check of XRDP service, and it appeared the following errors:

[image: systemctl status xrdp]

After that, I tried to change the `ssl_protocols` field in `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini` from `ssl_protocols=TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3` to `ssl_protocols=TLSv1, TLSv1.1` and then restart the XRDP service. Nothing changes, the same error still happens and the situation of XRDP service is the same!

Something is not right here, maybe I did something missing or was wrongly configured?

Comment: this can often be a result of the lack of a ruke in your input chain re iptables https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/linux-firewall ,  suggest you check the input chain rule created by this "firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=3389/tcp" actually exists and is in the correct line, ie before the "REJECT  all  --  *   *   0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0     reject-with icmp-host-prohibited" rule